# Did Jedi ever use expletives?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

From the depiction of (most) Jedi in the movies, we see them as being a bunch of law-abiding goody two shoes who run around keeping order in the galaxy. But I'm sure there were points where they'd get frustrated with a situation and wanted to express their disgust somehow.

Are there any instances in which a Jedi swears? Or anything that would qualify as swearing in the Star Wars universe, such as calling someone a 'scruffy looking nerf-herder'.

Comment: I think Kanan said "Karabast" once in Rebels but I can't recall the episode

Comment: There seem to be a few examples looking through http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang/Legends. For example, "sithspit" by Jedi such as Kyle Katarn and Jaden Korr, and "kriff" by Luke in front of his son Ben.

Comment: And I don't know what movies you watched but I saw the Jedi exploiting a slave army of clones, committing treason, etc. They didn't seem like a bunch of "law-abiding goody two shoes" to me.

Comment: Fair point @Null, there were of course the obvious examples of Qui Gon and Anakin who also didn't follow the Jedi code as strictly as others did.

Comment: Obi-Wan's growl in Attack of the Clones always catches me: "What *in the blazes* is he doing there?" It can be found also on the phrases and slang list in Wookieepedia.

Comment: You should know that there are several behavioral modes which could be classified by the colloquial “curse” or “swear”.  **Vain oath**, **expletive**, and **derogation** are a few examples.

Comment: Damn, and I just rewatched ESB a few weeks ago.  Did Yoda utter any expletives or the like when he was fighting with R2 for Luke's little lamp?

Comment: @Essen Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: The Jedi in the prequels frequently say "Jar Jar", which I'm given to believe is some kind of huge insult/slur.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are a lot of "sithspawn" curses in the Star Wars books,

Comment: Haha!   I posted a comment calling the question a load of poodoo and apparently someone flagged it or a mod deleted it of their own accord.  So apparently that is not obvious enough a joke, or people take their SW expletives very seriously!   For the record, it was a joke.

Comment: Jedi philosophy probably discourages swearing in anger, because anger leads to hate, and hate leads to suffering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the Jedi did occasionally swear.

For example, Obi-Wan Kenobi:

[image]