# What are some Star Wars-specific swear words?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, languages

Swear words that aren't derived from Earth-speak but rather from within the Star Wars universe's context alone e.g. sithspit

Comment: Of course "nerf herder" is the most famous one.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang is probably a good starting point

Comment: There's probably a good reason why Chewbacca never gets subtitles.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157041/did-jedi-ever-use-expletives

Comment: [Artoo was the most vulgar character of all time; they had to bleep out everything he said](http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/the-most-vulgar-character-of-all-time.jpg)

Comment: “Jar-Jar”, although I guess that only works out-of-universe.

Answer (score 18):

While not comprehensive, http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang offers a fairly impressive listing. Of note:

> Bantha fodder: The equivalent of "worthless"; a person or thing deemed
>   to have no value beyond something for a bantha to graze on.
>
> Choobies: A slang term for one's self or one's testicles.
>
> Dosh: An expletive used to express anger.
>
> Doshing: A derogatory modifier, as in "Take your doshin' hands off."
>
> E chu ta: A term spoken to C-3PO by E-3PO on Cloud City to which he
>   replies, "How rude."
>
> Feed the Sarlacc: To use the toilet.
>
> Karabast: A Lasat exclamation of frustration. Garazeb Orrelios was
>   fond of using this exclamation.
>
> Kriffing: This was an expletive. When Beck Ollet described a referee
>   as being "crooked as a kriffing Hutt," he was ordered off the
>   grav-ball field with the threat of suspension otherwise.
>
> Kung: This was Huttese for "scum," i.e. "U kulle rah doe kankee kung,"
>   meaning "You are my kind of scum."
>
> Moof-milker: A term for a dimwitted individual.
>
> Mother of Kwath!: This was an exclamation of aggravation.
>
> Nerfherder: An insult once used by Princess Leia Organa. It referred
>   to the animal by the same name.
>
> Nerve Burner: This insult suggested one was unstable.
>
> Not the brightest lightsaber in the galaxy: Unintelligent.
>
> Not the brightest star in the sky: Unintelligent.
>
> Peedunky: This Huttese insult was roughly equivalent to "punk."
>
> Piston-head: This derogratory phrase was sometimes used to describe
>   IG-86 sentinel droids.
>
> Poodoo: A Huttese term meaning "fodder," a coarse type of food for
>   livestock. Used often as a swear word.
>
> Pfassk: An adaptable expletive, as in "What the pfassk does sorry do
>   for anyone?"
>
> Skug: A common Zygerrian insult.
>
> Sleemo: This Huttese insult was pronounced slay-mo and translated as
>   "slimeball," a rude insult.
>
> Son of a bantha: This insult was once directed at Han Solo by Sana
>   Starros.
>
> Stang: This slang term of frustration was once employed by Beck Ollet
>   during a grav-ball match in reference to the opposing team's wing
>   striker.
>
> Svaper: Frid Kelio once referred to the athletic director Janus Fhurek
>   as a "dirty svaper."
>
> Tailhead: This was a derogatory slang term referring to members of the
>   Twi'lek race.
>
> Walking carpet: Leia Organa once applied this insulting term to
>   Chewbacca in reference to his shaggy coat of fur.
>
> Wastoid: A derogatory term.

Comment: You have Pfassk twice.

Comment: They clarify with it being "an adaptable expletive"

Comment: I suspect that some of the beeps and whistles that R2-D2 directs at C-3P0 might be expletives, as well :-).

Answer (score 1):

One that I have come across in the EU is *'Sithspawn'*

I first came across this in the Michael A. Stackpole novel X-Wing: Rogue Squadron. Lieutenant Corran Horn (Rogue 9 of Rogue Squadron) thinks to himself

> *Great, all I need is some **Sithspawn** hotshot pilot in that squint"*
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Wing: Rogue Squadron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-Wing:_Rogue_Squadron)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>Note that this is Rebel pilot slang. An 'Eyeball' is a standard TIE fighter, a 'Squint' is a TIE interceptor, a 'dupe' is a TIE bomber & 'Bright' is a TIE Advanced (Darth Vader's personal TIE fighter).</sup></sub>

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: I'm getting a bit tired of cleaning up your answers. There's some quality here, but can you *please* make at least some effort to [learn where capital letters go](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp) and how to use the top buttons to add quotes and links